# Django - Using multiple models for authentication

Tags: python, django, authentication, django-registration, custom-authentication

I am kind of new to django and I am concerned about can we use multiple models for authentication for different types of users for our application e.g for Customers use Customer model, for Suppliers use Supplier model and also keep default User registration model for administration use only? If so can you point me in the right direction, how it can be done? Which package should be used?
There is one way that I came around is by adding a foreign key to each model viz needed for authentication but that will involve joins in every query which could result in performance issues. I need to know if there is a better way. An also these custom models can benefit for all permissions stuff available in admin panel. 
Expert opinion will be really appreciated.

Comment: This is pretty opinion-based. I personally prefer to create profile models with OneToOne relationships back to the base user auth model. This is not the only way to do it, but IMO it's the simplest and most modular.

Comment: @souldeux in data extensive app this could cause performance issues because it involves joins.

Answer (score 0):

There are a few different options to handle that.
Maybe check first [the Django-docu](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/auth/customizing/).
I've you'ld like to customize it to authenticate your users with a mail-address, here is an example written by [knbk](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2615075/knbk) and [rahul-gupta](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4921103/rahul-gupta) on the ex-documentation:

> Django's default authentication works on username and password fields. Email authentication backend will authenticate users based on email and password.
>
> ```
> from django.contrib.auth import get_user_model
>
> class EmailBackend(object):
>     """
>     Custom Email Backend to perform authentication via email
>     """
>     def authenticate(self, username=None, password=None):
>         user_model = get_user_model() 
>         try:
>             user = user_model.objects.get(email=username)
>             if user.check_password(password): # check valid password
>                 return user # return user to be authenticated
>         except user_model.DoesNotExist: # no matching user exists 
>             return None 
>
>     def get_user(self, user_id):
>         user_model = get_user_model() 
>         try:
>             return user_model.objects.get(pk=user_id)
>         except user_model.DoesNotExist:
>             return None
> ```
>
> Add this authentication backend to the AUTHENTICATION_BACKENDS setting.
>
> ```
> # settings.py
> AUTHENTICATION_BACKENDS = (
>     'my_app.backends.EmailBackend', 
>     ... 
> )
> ```

Comment: I want to use multiple models for authenticating users. Is that possible?

Comment: @tahir there are two ways. either you extend your existing authentication system, or you create a new one.
Is it possible for you to explain, what you actually plan to do?

Comment: My application would have three different portals, one for administration, one for our customers and one for our suppliers. I want to use separate authentication system for each portal. And I would like to be able to benefit from permissions system in default admin cPanel. Is this possible?

Comment: I'm not quite sure if that'll work, but you can handle that an other way. Why don't you create a permissions based view system. all you need to do is add a small if case in your view. for example like that:`
from django.core.exceptions import PermissionDenied
from django.contrib.auth.decorators import login_required, 

@login_required
def your_view(request):
             user = request.user
             if user.has_perm('myapp.change_bar'):
                _code code code_
             ... etc.
             else:
                 raise PermissionDenied`